# Frame incorrect in parentVC and childVC after popping back to parentVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uipageviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I'm having problem were my views frames are completely wrong after return to the viewController by popping the current one.

My view hierarchy is as follows:

```
UITabbarController,
    UINavigationController
        HomeSwipeViewController (need as I cant put a UIPageViewController straight into a navController)
            UIPageViewController
                 HomeViewController
```

In the HomeSwipeViewController I have the pageViewController embedded in a containerView, the containerView has constraints and should be full to it's super (set in the storyboard):

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

[self.containerView addSubview:self.pageController.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.pageController.view addFullScreenConstraint]; // full to superView
```

Inside the homeViewController is a collectionView which you can tap and I push a ViewController on to the UINavigationController. This works fine but when I pop back to the HomeSwipeViewController, the frames are all incorrect.

Logs printed out in viewDidAppear of homeSwipeViewController:

First appears:

```
[12234:152630] containerView: <UIView: 0x7fea0046cdb0; frame = (0 0; 320 464); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea0046c450>>
[12234:152630] pageController.view: <_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x7fea0290b690; frame = (0 0; 320 464); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea02909f60>>
[12234:152630] self.view: <UIView: 0x7fea0285d2d0; frame = (0 64; 320 504); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea0285d1d0>>
```

After pop:

```
[12234:152630] containerView: <UIView: 0x7fea0046cdb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea0046c450>>
[12234:152630] pageController.view: <_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x7fea0290b690; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea02909f60>>
[12234:152630] self.view: <UIView: 0x7fea0285d2d0; frame = (0 64; 320 455); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea0285d1d0>>
```

I've tried calling setNeedsDisplay, setNeedsLayout and setNeedsUpdateConstraints in the viewDidAppear. Adding constraints all programmatically in viewDidLayoutSubViews.

No broken constraints are logged in the console.

I believe it has to to do with embedding the viewController because when I remove the UIPageViewController and add the homeViewContoller as the childViewController, the same results happen.

If I embed nothing there isn't a problem.

All views have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the constraints for the parent view controller (HomeSwipeViewController) in viewDidLayoutSubviews. I use only do it when self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

I think this is because the project uses both views that have been mordenised to Autolayout and frame based(autoresizing) views. It looks like pushing a VC with the view that doesn't have autolayout, removes the VC its coming from constraints or maybe it just inactivates the auto layout engine.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    if (self.view.superview) {

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{@"view": self.view}]];
        [self.view.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-64-[view]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.view}]];

    }

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

Any insight to why this works would be cool!